# Google Cloud: Cannot connect to server via SSH

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

Port is up, firewall disabled, but connection is rejected with message:

```
"Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer".
```

Other services in the same host are responding well.

SSH through Google Cloud Console gets the same error.

Is there any other method for Google Compute Engine to get shell?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to get shell, and it is through the serial port, a really useful feature Google Cloud provides.

There, I saw the error was about key file permissions:

```
Sep 30 10:51:02 localhost sshd: Permissions 0775 for '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key' are too open.
```

And by assigning 0600 perms to this file everything went back to normal.

Comment: I'm confused why using serial port can work around this problem? The doc says it still uses ssh keys.